# how to get selected string value from webpopup in corona sdk?

Tags: webview, coronasdk

In my application i used webpopup in that i have to get string from webpopup.now i used corona:close?=id to get the string but that will be encoded.how to get that string correctly.

```
<script>
var selObj = window.getSelection(); 
var selectedText = selObj.toString(); 
var texttemp='corona:close?id='; 
document.getElementById('myAnchor').href=texttemp+selectedText;
</script>
```

finally iam getting that string but that will look like below.

> %20achev%C3%A9s%20%5Cr%5Cn%20les%20cieux%20et

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL encoding converts characters into a format that can be transmitted over the Internet.
More info:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp
http://www.backbone.se/urlencodingUTF8.htm
https://gist.github.com/ignisdesign/4323051

You can decode that using this function:

```
function decondeUrl(str)
        str = string.gsub (str, "+", " ")
        str = string.gsub (str, "%%(%x%x)", function(h) return string.char(tonumber(h,16)) end)
        str = string.gsub (str, "\r\n", "\n")
        return str
end
```

More code snippets:
http://code.google.com/p/afrimesh/source/browse/branches/unstable/villagebus/lua/urlcode.lua?r=1105